# refactor IF statement with multiple returns

Tags: php, php-7

I have a code similar to this:

```
if($a) {
  return $a;
} elseif($b) {
  return $b;
} elseif($c) {
  return $c;
} else {
  return $d;
}
```

it is honestly not so looking good but I need to check the variables to respect some sort of priority order. I was guessing if there is a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `switch / case` where the condition is `TRUE`.

**Example:**

```
switch (TRUE) {

  case (isset($a)) : return $a; break;
  case (isset($b)) : return $b; break;
  case (isset($c)) : return $c; break;

  default : return $d;

}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
return $a ?? $b ?? $c ?? $d;
```

Note that below version 7.0 of PHP this operator is not supported.

As berend pointed out in a comment this does differ slightly from the code in your question. If `$a` is `FALSE` then it is defined and will be returned. If that's not what you want, you could fall back on the [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
return isset($a) ? $a : (isset($b) ? $b : (isset($c) ? $c : $d));
```

but in most usage cases the Null Coalescing Operator will do.

Comment: not sure this is the [desired outcome](https://3v4l.org/ons4M), if `$a === false` it returns `$a`, or is the test incorrect?

Comment: @berend Ah, looked at your example. That's interesting indeed, and makes sense. This does differ with the code in the question.

Comment: How about just: `$a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d`, that's short and [works](https://3v4l.org/FGa4N)

Comment: @berend: No, I get `Undefined variable: a` warnings when I use that.